# Unable to initialize external jQuery in Magento2

Tags: magento2.3

I would like to initialize `intlTelInput` for the country code column. I have done below,

in `requirejs.config.js` added below

```
var config = {
    deps: [
    "Ucs_Reson8/js/countryCode"
  ],
  paths: {
    'intlTelInput': 'Ucs_Reson8/js/intlTelInput',
  },
  shim: {
    'intlTelInput': {
      deps: ['jquery'],
      exports: 'jQuery.fn.intlTelInput',
    }
  }

};
```

Then in `countryCode.js` added below,

```
require([
'jquery',
'intlTelInput',
],
function($) {
        console.log('sample function 1234567');
        $(window).load(function() {
            jQuery("#country_code").intlTelInput({
                initialCountry: "ae",
                separateDialCode: true,
                preferredCountries: ["ae","bh","kw","om","qa","sa"],
                //onlyCountries: ["ae","bh","kw","om","qa","sa"],

            });
    });
    });
```

But I am getting the error as below in the browser console.

> TypeError: jQuery(...).intlTelInput is not a function

But in the page source I can see the `utilsIntel.js`

**NOTE: Before trying any other solution, it would be better to check jquery and plugin version compatibility**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined `jQuery` in the event function, you  just need to add it like this:

```
require([
'jquery',
'intlTelInput'
],
function($, jQuery) {

 "use strict";
 $(document).ready(function () { 
        console.log('sample function 1234567');
            jQuery("#country_code").intlTelInput({
                initialCountry: "ae",
                separateDialCode: true,
                preferredCountries: ["ae","bh","kw","om","qa","sa"]
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: No luck, when I use this it shows, jQuery is not a function

Comment: try redeploy static view files

Comment: yes, I've run deploy comment as well. Thats why it ready the latest change right?

Comment: well if that doesn't work try using $ only

Comment: `$("#country_code").intlTelInput`

Comment: Does it mean that neither jquery or intelTelinout jqueries intialized in my page?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92666/discussion-between-magefms-and-butterfly).